# Select Content of a database and show in View in Laravel

Tags: database, laravel

i want to show my 'angebote'

this is my controller:

```
public function showangebot($firma)
{
    $dataangebot['angebotDetails'] = Angebot::where('firma',$firma)->first();
    return view('user/einzelansicht',$dataangebot);
}
```

and this is my view:

```
<div class="card">
            <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
                <h5 class="mb-0">
                    <button class="btn btn-link" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                        {{$angebotDetails->stellenname}}
                    </button>
                </h5>
            </div>
```

this works so it shows me the first object
but i want to schow all so i delete the '->first()' in my controller 
and use a foreach in my view
so like this:

```
@foreach($angebotDetails as $angebotDetail)
```

it tells me this error:

```
"Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::$firma (View: C:\wamp\sites\j4ylara\resources\views\user\einzelansicht.blade.php)"
```

i dont know what the problem is because i use this all the time and everything works but not now

if i use ->get() instead of ->first() or if i use this

```
$dataangebot['angebotDetails'] = DB::table('angebots')
    ->where('firma',$firma)
    ->get();
```

it tells me this:

```
Property [firma] does not exist on this collection instance. (View: C:\wamp\sites\j4ylara\resources\views\user\einzelansicht.blade.php)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using  *get* instead of *first* in your controller. The get function retrieves a Collection, which is what you need to pass to, and iterate through, in your view.

```
public function showangebot($firma)
{
   $dataangebot['angebotDetails'] = Angebot::where('firma',$firma)->get();
   return view('user/einzelansicht',$dataangebot);
}
```

In reference to:

```
Property [firma] does not exist on this collection instance. (View: C:\wamp\sites\j4ylara\resources\views\user\einzelansicht.blade.php)
```

you are most likely referring to **firma** outside of the *@foreach* loop. Here is what you should try

```
@foreach($angebotDetails as $angebotDetail)
    {{ $angebotDetail->firma }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: ah okey but now i can only show {{ $angebotDetail->firma }} but if i want {{ $angebotDetail->stellenname }} it tells me: Property [stellenname] does not exist on this collection instance.

Comment: Are you asking for stellenname inside or outside the @foreach loop?

Answer (score 0):

**This is the easiest way.**

```
public function showangebot($firma)
{
    $angebots = Angebot::where('firma',$firma)->get();
    return view('user/einzelansicht',compact('angebots'));
}
```

**And then in your view file call your variable.**

```
@foreach ($angebots as $angebot)
<div class="card">
            <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
                <h5 class="mb-0">
                    <button class="btn btn-link" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                        {{$angebot->stellenname}}
                    </button>
                </h5>
            </div>

@endforeach
```